# Find row of an item template control in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview in ASP.NET with a item template which holds a drop down list. I have an event for the drop down list (selected index changed) in which I need to figure out which row, in the gridview, this control resides in. Anyone know how to accomplish this?  (I add more rows later, so this is why I need the row I am in.)

```
<asp:gridview ID="grdTest" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Query Line" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Table Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>


protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Grab the row of the control here!
    int row = 0;
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender; // How?
}
```

Comment: Try working with `ddl.Parent` or `ddl.Parent.Parent` etc, until you get to the `GridViewRow`. Then you should be able to retrieve which row it is with the `RowIndex` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it like this,

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList) sender;
  GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) ddl.NamingContainer;
  int rowIndex = row.RowIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below code will help you

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim gvrow As GridViewRow = CType(sender, DropDownList).NamingContainer
    Dim index As Integer = CType(gvrow, GridViewRow).RowIndex
End Sub
```

Comment: That's VB.NET but I understand what you are getting at